# the ul-li elements styling is not correct

Tags: css, html, html-lists

Hi I am trying to build a list (code shared at: http://jsfiddle.net/jLM4J/).

My question is that though the list elements should not be overlapping, why is my list overlapping the first item, where I am trying to display the user details.

Even if i replace the user li element with a separate div outside/inside ul(http://jsfiddle.net/yYEhS/1/), the ul list still keeps overlapping my element while it should not because my element is div which displays as a block.

Can anyone please help as this is screwing my mind up.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of a `float:left;` in your user div declaration.  Remove it like so, and it works:

```
.user-image {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: url('../../images/user.png') no-repeat center center;
    margin: 1px;
    border: 1px @border-style @border-color;
}
```

Without a design to look at, it's hard to know why you might have had that float: left there.

If you need it to align left to the PAGE, it needs to be outside of the ul.
If you want it to align left within the page, then assign `text-align:left;` to the li elements.

Comment: thanks for the response. My intention of putting the float:left there was that the image should float on left, while the user name and user requests can appear on right. The list would follow on vertically below. I also did not understand why ids it breaking my one liner '3 requests pending' into three different lines, instead of increasing the width of the div itself...

Comment: i later achieved it using negative margin for user image: http://jsfiddle.net/cDgzB/1/